# Problem about normal family, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

thanks for read me. Im in trouble again:

Let $F \subseteq H(\Omega)$ normal family, where $H$ is the set of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$, a open set in $\mathbb C$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that

{ $\delta f$, $f \in F$ } $ \subseteq B(0,\epsilon)$.

The metric is

$d(f,g):=
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n} || f-g ||_{\infty,K_{n}}}{1+|| f-g ||_{\infty,K_{n}}}
$

Where $|| f-g ||_{\infty,D} = sup_{z\in D} |f(z)|$

My efforts were useless. Sorry if this had already been asked, I do not know the mathematical words in English.

Comment: Is $F$ normal here? Also, is $B(0,\varepsilon)$ the ball in $H(\Omega)$? With what metric?

Comment: yes. Sorry. I already edited it

Comment: I'm confused. If $f\in F$, then $\delta f$ is a holomorphic function. Meanwhile, $B(0,\varepsilon)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So how can $\delta f\in B(0,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: {$\delta f$ such that $f \in F$} is a family of functions, and B(0,$\epsilon$) is a subset of $R^2$

Comment: Right, so how can one be a subset of the other? They're objects of different types; one is a set of functions, the other a set of (complex) numbers.

Comment: In the sense that, if $g \in ${ $\delta f$ such that $f \in F$}, then the image of g have module less than $\epsilon$, maybe

Comment: By Montel's Theorem, $F$ is uniformly locally bounded, which tells you that the family $\{f|_K:f\in F\}$ is uniformly bounded for every compact set $K\subset \Omega$. This implies your result when considering the restrictions to arbitrary compact subsets of the domain, but I'm not seeing how to extend it to all of $\Omega$.

Comment: I think the theorem is false as stated: Consider $F = \{ 1/z \}$ which is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Then $F$ is a normal family, but it is not bounded on its domain. So for $\epsilon = 1$, say, no $\delta$ will put the image of $\delta / z$ into $B(0,1)$.

Comment: You're right. I was wrong. The metric in question is the following:

Comment: $d(f,g):=
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n} || f-g ||_{\infty,K_{n}}}{1+|| f-g ||_{\infty,K_{n}}}
$

Where $|| f-g ||_{\infty,D} = sup_{z\in D} |f(z)|$